# Issue with IE8- Rendering is too slow and shows page not responding

Tags: internet-explorer

My app is displaying some data in tabular form (400 rows and 7 columns visible+ 10 columns hidden, couple of columns are drop down). Strangely the page loads fine in less than a minute on almost all the browsers but IE8. A careful testing showed that if I simply removed the hidden columns from the record, the performance becomes much better. This makes me think that time taken (and browser not responding) has actually nothing to do with the type of rendering, but just amount of data being rendered.

Additional info(not sure if this is helpful) : The page is actually JSP page, using Jquery and some images.

As this is strictly IE8 specific, I am expecting someone must have faced the same issue? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is IE8 issue.. live with it